# Differentiating rows' elements in Prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have a table that contains in each row an input and a "save" image.

```
<td>
 <div id="acp_1" style="margin-left:100px;display: inline">
   <input size="10" type="text" value="11:00" name="acpr_1" id="acpr_1" />
   <span class="modify-listener" id="ml_1">
     <img id="save_1" src="/images/skin/database_save.png" alt="modify"/>
   </span>
 </div>
</td>

<td>
 <div id="acp_2" style="margin-left:100px;display: inline">
   <input size="10" type="text" value="11:00" name="acpr_2" id="acpr_2" />
   <span class="modify-listener" id="ml_2">
     <img id="save_2" src="/images/skin/database_save.png" alt="modify"/>
   </span>
 </div>
</td>
```

The __*number* pattern is used to differentiate one row's element from another.

I need to capture the click event on the image, so I can save the input's value in the backend. Something like:

```
Event.observe('modify-listener', 'click', function(){
   ....
```

How can I detect which row's image was clicked so I can call an Ajax function with the right values?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The technique you are searching for is called **[event delegation](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/06/30/event-delegation-in-javascript/)**. It basically means that you handle an event on a higher lever of the tree so as to have **only one event handler instead of many**.

What you need to do is to find the **container** element that includes all the images (like the table that they are in), and use it as the **base for event handling**, and give its id to `Event.observe`. Then you can find out which img was clicked by using the `Event.findElement` method.

```
Event.observe('target', 'click', function(event) {
  alert( Event.findElement(event, 'IMG').id ); // e.g.: save_1
});
```

*assuming that your table has an id `#target`*

You can find a working **[demo here](http://jsbin.com/emibi3)**.